# mod_wsgi Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

**Follow flask's doc**：

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Apache/2.4.10
flask 0.12.2

**Directory Structure：**

```
├── movie_douban.py
├── movie_douban.wsgi
└── app
    ├── web
    ├── models
    ├── templates
    └── static
```

**movie_douban.wsgi：**

```
activate_this='/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/movie_douban-og6kh8C1/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/movie_douban-og6kh8C1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/')

from movie_douban import app as application
```

**Apache：**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gdd.python.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess movie_douban user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/movie_douban/movie_douban.wsgi

    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/python-error_log"
    <Directory /var/www/movie_douban>
        WSGIProcessGroup movie_douban
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache Error:**

```
[Sun Apr 29 10:59:56.835279 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16942] [remote 172.17.0.1:50790] mod_wsgi (pid=16942): Target WSGI script '/var/www/movie_douban/movie_douban.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Apr 29 10:59:56.835321 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16942] [remote 172.17.0.1:50790] mod_wsgi (pid=16942): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/movie_douban/movie_douban.wsgi'.
[Sun Apr 29 10:59:56.835470 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16942] [remote 172.17.0.1:50790] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Apr 29 10:59:56.835603 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16942] [remote 172.17.0.1:50790]   File "/var/www/movie_douban/movie_douban.wsgi", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Apr 29 10:59:56.837206 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16942] [remote 172.17.0.1:50790]     with open(activate_this) as file_:
[Sun Apr 29 10:59:56.837265 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16942] [remote 172.17.0.1:50790] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/movie_douban-og6kh8C1/bin/activate_this.py'

root@345ad0ab8386:/var/www/movie_douban# ls -l /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/movie_douban-og6kh8C1/bin/activate_this.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1137 Apr 28 03:31 /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/movie_douban-og6kh8C1/bin/activate_this.py
```

What should I do?

Comment: Unrelated, but also read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for recommended way of activating the virtual environment. It is better to use the ``python-home`` option of ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` directive.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton
i don't configure the python-home option of WSGIDaemonProcess,i added two options in the movie.wsgi: sys.path.insert(0, '/home/virtualenvs/movie-3QK-yS3b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/') sys.path.insert(0, '/data/movie') it works

Comment: As I said, doing what you are doing with ``site-packages`` is not the recommended way. It may work, but doing it that way can hide other problems with your setup that will come back and bite you later. It is better to use the method recommended by the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission denied error is usually caused by incorrect owner, group, or file mode setting of the file to be loaded or one of the subdirectories leading to it. Another possible cause is SELinux, but only if it is enabled and in enforcing mode.

```
Permission denied: '/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/movie_douban-og6kh8C1/bin/activate_this.py'
```

In this case, almost certainly the Apache process has no access to `/root` directory (i.e. admin's home directory), because it is running under UID of apache or httpd user.

You should move your virtualenv files to a more suitable location.

Comment: thanks，it works,i move virtualenv to /home.but it's have import error,i need to see again